# Extend UEventObserver.java

Tags: android, gpio

Hey!
For observing GPIO interrupts i want to create an observer class which should be a subclass of UEventObserver.java which finds in frameworks/base/core/java/android/os. The problem is, that this class is not contained in the standard SDK android.jar. Does anybody have got an idea how to extend from this class?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I did a search on all android.jar on my Mac with api level 10, 15 and 16, and only found the class in api level 10. It seems to be deprecated somehow, but I can't find any information around that.

```
find . | xargs grep UEventObserver
Binary file ./android-10/data/android/os/UEventObserver$UEvent.class matches
Binary file ./android-10/data/android/os/UEventObserver$UEventThread.class matches
Binary file ./android-10/data/android/os/UEventObserver.class matches
Binary file ./android-10/data/layoutlib.jar matches
Binary file ./android-10/images/system.img matches
Binary file ./android-15/data/layoutlib.jar matches
Binary file ./android-16/data/layoutlib.jar matches
```

Comment: The class is hidden, so it isn't available from the standard apis avaialble in the SDK. It's still used internally by the USBManager service.

Answer (score 0):

The class is hidden part of frameworks, so it isn't exposed via the normal sdk API's that Apps use.